# DevExpress PivotGrid (Silverlight) : Popup Menus don't popup

Tags: silverlight, popup, devexpress, contextmenu

We are using DevExpress Silverlight PivotGrid (11.2.7). The problem is that none of the popups work as one would expect.

Here is the xaml code (note that all of these properties are True by default and don't need to be set)

```
<dxpg:PivotGridControl 
x:Name="pivotGrid"

... data bindings ...

IsFieldValuePopupMenuEnabled="True"
IsHeaderMenuEnabled="True"
IsHeaderAreaMenuEnabled="True"
/>
```

Once the host control for the grid is shown and the data is loaded right-clicking on any of the relevant areas doesn't bring either of the popups (there are 3).

Strangely (or not so strangely) in the sample SL project provided by devex everything works as it should.

The one (significant) difference between the sample app and our project is that we are using MEF and relevant .xaps are loaded dynamically based on which user logged in and some other stuff.

We have tried a lot stuff to figure out what is wrong but haven't managed to find anything even remotely relevant. Here is what we have tried :

- Adding the pivotgrid to the host tabpage in codebehind after imports have been satisfied;
- Setting / resetting properties mentioned above after imports from codebehind;
- Adding the control to the startup page of the project before the MEF madness kicks in;
- We also tried to popup the menus manually by inheriting from the pivotgrid control, but that has not yielded much;
- Enabled RedrawRegions to make sure the popup is not popping 'under'. It's not;

Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this was some bug in the version we were using at the time.
After updating to 12.1 everything works like it should without any tinkering from our side.

Looks like devex guys have bugs too...who knew right :)